# Gutenberg Block Development: Only one RichText content is saving

Tags: gutenberg-blocks

I added two `RichText` components in my block.

```
registerBlockType( 'hallmark/gray-content-container', {
        title: __( 'Gray Content Container' ),
        icon: 'grid-view',
        category: 'hallmark-blocks',
        keywords: [
            __( 'Hallmark gray content' ),
            __( 'Hallmark' ),
            __( 'Gray content container' ),
        ],

        attributes:{
            contentHeading: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'children',
                selector: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6'
            },
            textContent: {
                type: 'string'
            }
        },

        edit: function( props ) {

            var textContent = props.attributes.textContent;
            var contentHeading = props.attributes.contentHeading;

            function onChangeTextContent( content ) {
                props.setAttributes( { textContent: content } );
            }

            function onChangeHeading (heading) {
                props.setAttributes( { contentHeading: heading} );
            }

            return (
                <div className={ props.className }>
                    <label className="editor-content-section-label">Content for gray section</label>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="h1"
                        value={contentHeading}
                        onChange={onChangeHeading}
                        placeholder={ __( 'Add a heading' ) }
                        keepPlaceholderOnFocus
                    />
                    <RichText
                        tagName="p"
                        className={props.className}
                        onChange={onChangeTextContent}
                        value={textContent}
                        placeholder={ __( 'Add content' ) }
                        keepPlaceholderOnFocus
                    />
                </div>
            );
        },

        save: function( props ) {
            //return null;
            return(
                <div className={props.className}>
                    <div className="gray-bg">
                        <div className="constrain content">
                            <RichText.Content tagName="h1" value={ attributes.contentHeading } />
                            <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ attributes.textContent } />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );

        },
    } );
```

I tried two different approaches to save the data.

Using default `save()` function

```
save: function( props ) {
      return(
         <div className={props.className}>
            <div className="gray-bg">
                <div className="constrain content">
                    <RichText.Content tagName="h1" value={ attributes.contentHeading } />
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ attributes.textContent } />
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     );
},
```

**Saving it in PHP:**

Using `render_callback` method (Using `return null;` from block's default `save()` function.

```
register_block_type( 'hallmark/white-content-container', array(
    'render_callback' => 'hall_render_white_content'
) );

function hall_render_white_content( $atts ) {
   $heading = $atts['contentHeading'];
   $raw_content = $atts['textContent'];
   $full_content = $heading . $raw_content;
   // var_dump($full_content);

   $content = hall_clean_shortcode_block_content( $full_content );

   return '<div class="gray-bg"><div class="constrain content">' . $content . '</div></div>';
}
```

`atts['contentHeading']` element does not exist at all in `$atts` array. When I check `var_dump( $attas );` it has `textContent`element present.

The problem is both approaches are only saving the `textContent`. `contentHeading` is not at all saving.

What I am missing?

Comment: For debugging use `console.log(props.attributes)` inside your edit function and observe if the values of `contentHeading` is changing or not when you edit. `edit()` function will be called each time if the state or props of component changes. As per my lucky guess the source of `contentHeading` should be 'text' instead of 'children'.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you so much @MehmoodAhmad :)

Comment: Glad to here that. Adding proper answer below for others please accept that so that it can help others.

Comment: One question. I wanted it to save from server side using `render_callback`. My function is `function hall_render_gray_content( $atts ) {...}`. But it is never getting the value of `$atts['contentHeading'];` even when I have it. When I am trying this the red `Publish error` notification is coming up. What could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry I didn't work with `serverSideRendering` until now. I have find out that mostly we don't need `serverSideRendering`. So can you please explain why you are using that so that we can discuss whether you need that or not.

We only need server side rendering when our live content changes with time like our latest posts if the content is static and we only need to edit it from back-end then there is no need for server side rendering.

Comment: I am not using `serverSideRendering` component. I have written the approach in my original question labeled as "Saving it in PHP"

Comment: are you using acf?

Comment: no. there is no custom fields in it.

Comment: Okay, then this is serversiderendering block and I haveno experience with it until now. For info look at the latest post component of Gutenberg from GitHub repo.l because that will help you to find the problem.

Comment: today I worked with dynamic blocks and faced same problem. I noticed that I will only receive values if I update the attributes at least once via `setAttributes`. Are you sure that you are doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging use `console.log(props.attributes)` inside your edit function and observe if the values of `contentHeading` is changing or not when you edit. edit() function will be called each time if the state or props of component changes. As per my lucky guess the source of `contentHeading` should be 'text' instead of `children`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

`attributes:{
            contentHeading: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'children',
                selector: 'h1'
            },
            textContent: {
                type: 'string'
                selector: 'p'
            }
        },`

I think the selectors have to exactly match what is set in the `save` method.

`<div className="constrain content">
                            <RichText.Content tagName="h1" value={ attributes.contentHeading } />
                            <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ attributes.textContent } />
                        </div>`

I think you also need a unique selector, so if you had two RichText paragraphs, you could do

`textContentA: {
                type: 'string'
                selector: 'p.content-a'
            }
            textContentB: {
                type: 'string'
                selector: 'p.content-b'
            }`